# Json returns 'null'

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, cordova

I am currently using Phonegap along with xcode to make an IPhone App.

I'm just trying a simple Json call to get a query from a database (php) and it's returning Null.

I have Whitelisted the domain in the .plist file for phonegap. Here is m code:

```
    $.getJSON('"http://slc0013.pickaweb.co.uk/~bengeor1/fixtures.php",', function(data) {
        alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
        //alert (data.item1+" "+data.item2+" "+data.item3); //further debug
        $('#resultLog').html("<p>item1="+data.id+" item2="+data.home_team+" item3="+data.away_team+"</p>");
    });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);


 // Set your return content type
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$db = "localhost";
$db_name = "xxx";
$db_user = "xxx";
$db_pwd = "xxxx";

$con = mysql_connect($db, $db_user, $db_pwd);
if (!$con) {
     $status = 11; //database error
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
     if (!$db_selected) {

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM Fixtures";
$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

$num = mysql_numrows($result);


$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows)


?>
```

If you run just the php file it displays the correct results.

Would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($rows)` shows what?

Comment: Do you get data at all from db?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the rows from the database. Wen you go on the php page directly the results show just using the json request in Xcode doesn't seem to be processing the json.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the first line:

```
$.getJSON('"http://slc0013.pickaweb.co.uk/~bengeor1/fixtures.php",', function(data) {
```

to this:

```
$.getJSON("http://slc0013.pickaweb.co.uk/~bengeor1/fixtures.php", function(data) {
```

Comment: Dont seem to be getting anything when I change the function structure. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having problem with url `'"http://slc0013.pickaweb.co.uk/~bengeor1/fixtures.php",'` should be `"http://slc0013.pickaweb.co.uk/~bengeor1/fixtures.php"` I guess

Comment: Dont seem to be getting anything when I change the function structure. The alert doesn't pop up now. Thank you for the suggestion though!